# ejecutar un .jar en servidor de aplicaciones weblogic

Tags: java, weblogic

buenas amigos, estoy desarrollando una aplicación que se va a ejecutar cada cierto tiempo, al principio lo cree que como una aplicacion, el metodo se ejecuta al tiempo indicado con la anotación `@Schedule(minute = "*/3", hour = "*", persistent = false)`, pero bien, como ahora no se va a necesitar una vista como tal, y para no estar desplegando un archivo `.WAR`, pense en crearlo como un .JAR, ahora bien cree el `.JAR` y el metodo que se ejecutaria con el `main` pero no tengo idea de como hacer que un `.JAR` desplegado en un servidor de aplicaciones weblogic se ejecute cada cierto tiempo, por ahi lei que con un cron job o crons pero la verdad no tengo mucho conocimiento de ello, espero puedan sugerirme alguna otra idea o metodo, gracias

Comment: ¿Tu webLogic está en un linux?, efectivamente  el job lo podrás configurar desde el cron tab para lanzarrlo, te creas un pequeño shell que llame al jar y el cron controla cuando lanzarlo.

Comment: uno para pruebas en windows y en produccion en linux amigo, agradezco tu comentario, se tienes algun tutorial o link a donde dirigirme te lo agradezco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo una forma de como yo mando a llamar un job que básicamente es un javaApplication (.jar), para ello  se hace uso del crontab y un shell que manda a ejecutar el jar.

**¿Qué es Crontab?**

`Crontab` es un simple archivo de texto que guarda una lista de comandos a ejecutar en un tiempo especificado por el usuario. Crontab verificará la fecha y hora en que se debe ejecutar el script o el comando, los permisos de ejecución y lo realizará en el background. Cada usuario puede tener su propio archivo crontab, de hecho el /etc/crontab se asume que es el archivo crontab del usuario root, cuando los usuarios normales (e incluso root) desean generar su propio archivo de crontab, entonces utilizaremos el comando crontab.

`Crontab` es la manera mas sencilla de administrar tareas de cron en sistemas multiusuario, ya sea como simple usuario de sistema o usuario root.

**Creando  el shell que llamará al jar :**

```
#!/bin/bash

#ejecuta una llamada a un jar el cual edita los archivos rechazados por intelar, modifica fecha y secuencial
# una vez editados son enviados a intelar

rootWFL=$( cd `dirname $0` >/dev/null; pwd );

        EXITCODE=;                                   
                #funcion que ejecuta el jar
                RunJava 
                EXITCODE=$?;                                        

                DISPLAY "El exit code ::--->  $EXITCODE";

              if [ "$EXITCODE" != "0" ]
                then
                    DISPLAY "System exit es diferente de 0 , finalizo con error -1  "
                else            
                    DISPLAY "Ejecución correcta de jar  ::---> ";
                    D
                fi          

# FUNCION PARA EJECUTAR JAVA 
function RunJava
{
echo "Mandando llamar jar con ruta "
    #ejecuta java, puedes indicar la ruta donde está o pasarla por variable
    java $DEBUG -jar $rootDir/mijarJob.jar ;
}
```

**¿Cómo Agregar tareas a crontab?**

Ejecutamos la edición del crontab con `crontab -e`, en algunas distros (como ubuntu) nos da la opción de elegir el editor de textos que deseemos, los demás nos quedamos con vi. El archivo crontab lucirá algo así.

> ## m h dom mon dow user command

**donde**:

- m corresponde al minuto en que se va a ejecutar el script, el valor
  va de 0 a 59
- h la hora exacta, se maneja el formato de 24 horas, los valores van
  de 0 a 23, siendo 0 las 12:00 de la medianoche.
- dom hace referencia al día del mes, por ejemplo se puede especificar
  15 si se quiere ejecutar cada dia 15
- dow significa el día de la semana, puede ser numérico (0 a 7, donde 0
  y 7 son domingo) o las 3 primeras letras del día en inglés: mon, tue,
  wed, thu, fri, sat, sun.
- user define el usuario que va a ejecutar el comando, puede ser root,
  u otro usuario diferente siempre y cuando tenga permisos de ejecución
  del script.
- command refiere al comando o a la ruta absoluta del script a
  ejecutar, ejemplo: /home/usuario/scripts/actualizar.sh, si acaso
  llama a un script este debe ser ejecutable

**Ejemplo de tareas  con el crontab**

> 15 10 * * * usuario /home/usuario/scripts/RunJava.sh

Ejecutará el script actualizar.sh a las 10:15 a.m. todos los días

> 15 22 * * * usuario /home/usuario/scripts/RunJava.sh

Ejecutará el script actualizar.sh a las 10:15 p.m. todos los días

00 10 * * 0 root apt-get -y update Usuario root
Ejecutará una actualización todos los domingos a las 10:00 a.m

> 45 10 * * sun root apt-get -y update

Usuario root ejecutará una actualización todos los domingos (sun) a las 10:45 a.m

> 30 7 20 11 * usuario /home/usuario/scripts/RunJava.sh

El día 20 de noviembre a las 7:30 el usuario correra el script

> 30 7 11 11 sun usuario /home/usuario/scripts/pastel_con_velitas.sh

El día 11 de noviembre a las 7:30 a.m. y que sea domingo, el usuario festejará

> 01 * * * * usuario /home/usuario/scripts/molestorecordatorio.sh

Un molesto recordatorio cada minuto de cada hora todos los días (NO recomendable).

**Igual se pueden manejar rangos especiales:**

> 30 17 * * 1,2,3,4,5

A las 5:30 de la tarde todos los días de lunes a viernes.

> 00 12 1,15,28 * *

A las 12 del día todos los días primero, quince y 28 de cada mes (ideal para nóminas)

Si esto resulta confuso, crontab maneja cadenas especiales para definir estos rangos.

- **@reboot** Ejecuta una vez, al inicio
- **@yearly** ejecuta sólo una vez al año: 0 0 1 1 *
- **@annually** igual que @yearly
- **@monthly** ejecuta una vez al mes, el día primero: 0 0 1 * *
- **@weekly** Semanal el primer minuto de la primer hora de la semana. 0 0 * 0″.
- **@daily** diario, a las 12:00A.M. 0 0 * * *
- **@midnight** igual que @daily
- **@hourly** al primer minuto de cada hora: 0 * * * *

**Ejemplo  de mi crontab:**

```
# and what command to run for the task
# 
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').# 
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
# 
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
# 
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
# 
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
# 
# m   h  dom mon dow   command
  0   8   *   *  1-7    /home/usuario/scripts/RunJava.sh >> /home/usuario/scripts/logCron/runjava.cron.log 2>&1
```

Igual manera podrías buscar otros formas   empleando otras herramientas como  [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/)

Comment: muchas gracias ventur, ahorita realizando pruebas cree fue un batch, claro ejecutandolo yo mismo me ejecuta el .jar de forma correcta, si un cron puede ejecutar un  shell, asumo que pudiera realizar lo mismo con un archivo .BAT correcto?

Comment: Correcto, puedes usar un .bat o emular los comandos linux con **Cygwin64**